# How to match regex occurences from the top to bottom

Tags: php, regex, recursion, template-engine

I'm trying to create a PHP Template Engine for study reasons.

suppose we have the follow *array*:

```
$regexList = [
  'varPattern' => '/{{\s*\$(.*?)\s*}}/',
  'loopPattern' => '/@for\((.*?)\)\s*{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}/',
  'statementPattern' => '/@if\((.*?)\)\s*{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}/'
]
```

and the follow *functions*:

```
getVar($varName);
loop($arrayName);
getStatementResult($booleanExpression);
```

and the *string* bellow:

```
$string = '

<span>{{ $fullName }}</span>

@for($names as $name)
{{
  @if($name == 'Eleandro)
  {{
    <p>{{ $name }}</p>
  }}
}} ';
```

The idea is to read the *string* from top to bottom and relying on the list of *regular expressions* find the result and give it to the correct *function*.

For example: The first thing to find has to be `{{$string}}`, so we pass the *variable* name to the `getVar($matchedVarName)` *function*.

Next has to be `@loop(){{ }}`, so, we call `loop($matchedArrayName);`

and inside the *loop* has to be finded the `@if(){{ }}`, so, we get the result and give to the `getStatementResult($matchedBooleanExpression)` with the value matched.

How can i do this in the right order (top to bottom)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you use the **`PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`** flag for [`preg_match_all`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). What that flag will do, is change the captured matches to include the offset in the pattern string. Now, the only thing we need to do is walk over all matches in the same order as their offset dictates.

That's a bit tricky, but definitely possible. My approach is the following:

1. Create an array of the matches per regular expression. Since you have three regular expressions, this will be an array with three values. Each value is simply the `$matches` matched by `preg_match_all` for that regular expression.
   *Important note: the matches are ordered by their offset within each array.*
2. Create an array of indexes per regular expression. We will use this to keep track of where we are for each regular expression. This is initialized to `[0, 0, 0]`. To make it more generic and let it handle any number of regular expressions, I did this using [`array_fill`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).
3. While not all matches were handled...

   1. Determine the next match to handle. This will be the regular expression of which the next match has the minimum offset. I wrote a small `minIndex` function for this.
   2. Call the appropriate function (hardcoded in `$functions` below) with the value of the matched group. At this point, we know which function to call because we know which regular expression created this particular match.

      If you would have been fine with calling the same function for all matches, we could have just merged all matches in a single array and sorted them by offset.
   3. Increment the index of the regular expression that matched.

At this point, I should remark that the last two regular expressions in your example don't match at all. This is because there are instances of `{` and `}` in the loop and statement. For the sake of demonstration, I simply cut off a part of those regular expressions, so they only match the condition of the loop/statement.

The below script will print this.

```
getVar('fullName')
loop('$names as $name')
getStatementResult('$name === "Eleandro"')
getVar('name')
```

This, I believe, is the output you'd expect.

```
// functions
function getVar($varName) {
    echo "getVar('$varName')\n";
}

function loop($arrayName) {
    echo "loop('$arrayName')\n";
}

function getStatementResult($booleanExpression) {
    echo "getStatementResult('$booleanExpression')\n";
}

// input
$string = '

<span>{{ $fullName }}</span>

@for($names as $name)
{{
  @if($name === "Eleandro")
  {{
    <p>{{ $name }}</p>
  }}
}} ';

// helper functions
function minIndex($arr) {
    $i = 0; $l = count($arr);
    $min = false; $minI = -1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; ++$i) {
        if ($arr[$i] === false)  continue; // skip non numbers
        if ($min === false || $arr[$i] < $min) {
            $min = $arr[$i];
            $minI = $i;
        }
    }
    return $minI;
}

// regular expressions
$regexList = [
    'varPattern' => '/{{\s*\$(.*?)\s*}}/',
    'loopPattern' => '/@for\((.*?)\)\s*{{/',
    'statementPattern' => '/@if\((.*?)\)\s*{{/'
];

// functions to map above regexes to
$functions = ['getVar', 'loop', 'getStatementResult'];
// matches per regex
$matchesAll = [];

// combine the above regexes into a single one, run that
foreach ($regexList as $name => $regex) {
    unset($matches);
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $matchesAll[] = $matches;
}

// walk over the matches in order of offset in string
// current match per regex
$indexes = array_fill(0, count($regexList), 0);
// number of matches per regex
$counts = array_map(function($m) { return count($m[0]); }, $matchesAll);
while ($indexes !== $counts) {
    $offsets = array_map(function($m, $i) {
            return (count($m[0]) > $i ? $m[0][$i][1] : false);
        }, $matchesAll, $indexes);
    $next = minIndex($offsets);
    call_user_func($functions[$next],
        $matchesAll[$next][1][$indexes[$next]][0]);
    $indexes[$next]++;
}
```

Comment: That's it, it's a little bit complicated to understand what's going on there, but is it. Im using preg_replace_callback now, so, i will try make a function to do this job using the preg_match_all with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag instead as you already done. Thanks man!

Comment: There's a problem, if i change the order of the functions to 
$functions = ['loop', 'getVar', 'getStatementResult']; it's dont get the var first, it's need to get the var first independently of the order. Otherwise i will not be able to execute a statement that appears before a var, it's will be statically, so, i will have to do always the same order: var, loop, statement, if someone create a template that starts with a statement it will fail!

Comment: The order of the functions must match the order of the regular expressions in `$regexList`. This code will report variables, statements and loops in the order they appear in the string, I thought this is what you require?